# User doesnt stay logged in when refreshing page NODE.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

Good day, I have made a login/register system, where the suer can login/logout and register.
I have made this with JWT and express.
Loggin in and logging out goes well, but when i refresh the page the user gets logged out. How could i fix this?

**tokens**

```
const { sign } = require("jsonwebtoken");

// const getToken = (user) => {
//     return jwt.sign(
//         // payload
//         {
//             _id: user._id,
//             name: user.name,
//             email: user.email,
//             isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
//         },
//         process.env.JWT_SECRET,
//         {
//             expiresIn: '24h',
//         }
//     )
// }

const createAccessToken = userId => {
    return sign(
        {
            userId,
        },
        process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {
            //expire time
            expiresIn: "15m",
        },
    );
};
//you can add versions of refresh tokens. So it only can be used once
const createRefreshToken = userId => {
    return sign(
        {
            userId,
        },
        process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {
            //expire time
            expiresIn: "7d",
        },
    );
};

const sendAccessToken = (req, res, accesstoken) => {
    res.send({
        accesstoken,
        email: req.body.email,
    });
};

const sendRefreshToken = (res, refreshtoken) => {
    //you can call it something different, so it
    //will be harder to track which token it is
    res.cookie("refreshtoken", refreshtoken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        path: "/refresh_token",
    });
};

module.exports = {
    createAccessToken,
    createRefreshToken,
    sendAccessToken,
    sendRefreshToken,
};
```

**Login route**

```
router.post("/signin", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            email: req.body.email,
        });
        if (!user)
            res.status(400).send({
                message: "User doesnt exist or password doesnt match",
            });

        const valid = await compare(req.body.password, user.password);
        if (!valid) throw new Error("Invalid password");

        const accesstoken = createAccessToken(user._id);
        const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken(user._id);
        sendRefreshToken(res, refreshtoken);
        sendAccessToken(req, res, accesstoken);

        res.send({
            email: user.email,
            refreshtoken: user.refreshtoken,
            sendAccessToken: sendAccessToken(req, res, accesstoken),
            refreshtoken,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        res.send({
            error: `${err.message}`,
        });
    }
});
```

**generating new token route:**

```
//generating new token
router.post("/refresh_token", (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.refreshtoken;
    //if we dont have a token in our request
    if (!token) return res.send({ accesstoken: "" });
    //if we have token. Verify it
    let payload = null;
    try {
        payload = verify(token, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.send({ accesstoken: "" });
    }
    //token is valid. Check if user exist
    const user = User.findOne(user => user._id === payload.userId);
    if (!user) return res.send({ accesstoken: "" });
    //user exists, check if refreshtoken exist on user
    if (user.refreshtoken !== token) {
        return res.send({ accesstoken: "" });
    }
    //token exist, create new refresh and accesstoken
    const accesstoken = createAccessToken(user._id);
    const refreshtoken = createRefreshToken(user._id);
    //update refresh token in database
    user.refreshtoken = refreshtoken;
    //all good now, send refreshtoken and accesstoken
    sendRefreshToken(res, refreshtoken);
    return res.send({ accesstoken });
});
```

**calling the refresh token**

```
export const userContext = React.createContext([]);
function App() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    const logoutCallback = async () => {
        await fetch("http://localhost:5000/users/logout", {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include",
        });
        //clear user from context
        setUser({});
        //navigate back to startpage

        alert("logged out");
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        async function checkRefreshToken() {
            const result = await (
                await fetch("http://localhost:5000/users/refresh_token", {
                    method: "POST",
                    credentials: "include", //needed to include the cookie
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                })
            ).json();
            setUser({
                accesstoken: result.accesstoken,
            });
            setLoading(false);
        }
        checkRefreshToken();
    }, []);
```

**login page**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { userContext } from "../../App";


function Login(props) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
    const [user, setUser] = useContext(userContext);
    

    
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const result = await (
            await fetch("http://localhost:5000/users/signin", {
                method: "POST",
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    email,
                    password,
                }),
            })
        ).json();
        if (result.accesstoken) {
            setUser({
                accesstoken: result.accesstoken,
                refreshtoken: result.refreshtoken,
            });
        } else {
            alert(result.error);
        }
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(user);
    }, [user]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className="login-h">Login</h1>

            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="login">
                <div className="login-form">
                    <label>email</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="email"
                        placeholder="username or email"
                        for="email"
                        onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                    ></input>
                    <br />
                    <label>Password</label>
                    <br />
                    <input
                        type="password"
                        placeholder="Password"
                        for="password"
                        onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                    ></input>
                    <br />
                    <p className="forget-pw">
                        <a href="/">Forgot password?</a>
                    </p>
                    <button>Login</button> <br />
                    <br />
                    {/* <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{result.error}</p> */}
                </div>
                <p className="have-ccl">
                    {" "}
                    No account yet?<a href="/signup">Signup</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Login;
```

Comment: Are you storing the token in local storage in the client?  If not, you're going to lose the token on every refresh.

Comment: clearly the issue is with the client. Like @jfriend00 says u have to write a logic in the client that stores the auth and refresh token to make it persistant.